# UISearchBar detect when user stop type and don't search immediately so detect pause

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, text, uisearchbar

i'm searching implementing a UISearchbar that retrieve information from a url, and with the default method:

```
 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
```

i can detect immediately when the text change and perform the fetch of url, but in this way, the text type is slow because the iPhone is searching the url, so i want start the fetching of the url when the user is stop writing for some second, so i want detect the pause of the typing to refresh the table view retrieving the information by the url. i have found a older post of this request and i have tried a solution that for me don't work:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(request:)     object:searchText];

    //.....

    [self performSelector:@selector(request:) withObject:searchText afterDelay:1.5];
}

-(void)request:(NSString *)myString
{
    NSLog(@"%@",myString);
}
```

in this way when i'm typing the request method is not called but when i stop typing it's called for every character i type, so is the same of the default method, i wrong something? or the implementation isn't correct?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like the provided solution isn't working because the "searchText" argument to `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` doesn't match the "searchText" argument to the previous call to `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`; so delayed searches get queued up every text change, and never cancelled.

You could use an `NSTimer` to delay the invocation of your search, and cancel the timer whenever the text changes: Give your object an `NSTimer` property or field; in `searchBar:textDidChange:` cancel any existing timer, then create and schedule a new one. The target of the timer should call your search method.

Something like (off the top of my head):

```
// in your class' .h object fields
{
  ...
  NSTimer *searchDelayer; // this will be a weak ref, but adding "[searchDelayer invalidate], searchDelayer=nil;" to dealloc wouldn't hurt
  ...
}

// in the .m

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
  [searchDelayer invalidate], searchDelayer=nil;
  if (YES /* ...or whatever validity test you want to apply */)
    searchDelayer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(doDelayedSearch:)
                                                   userInfo:searchText
                                                    repeats:NO];
}

-(void)doDelayedSearch:(NSTimer *)t
{
  assert(t == searchDelayer);
  [self request:searchDelayer.userInfo];
  searchDelayer = nil; // important because the timer is about to release and dealloc itself
}
```

Some programmers might be less cavalier about weak references than I'm being here.

*[edited to add:]*

Here's how you might do it if you were set on using cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget...:

```
// in your class' .h object fields
{
  ...
  NSString *priorSearchText; // this will NOT be a weak ref, so adding "[priorSearchText release]" to dealloc is also required
  ...
}

// in the .m
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
  [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                           selector:@selector(request:)
                                             object:priorSearchText];
  [priorSearchText release], priorSearchText = [searchText retain];
  if (YES /* ...or whatever validity test you want to apply */)
    [self performSelector:@selector(request:)
               withObject:searchText
               afterDelay:1.5];
}
```

I don't think I've ever used cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:... for real, so I don't know if it hides any surprises. If you have trouble, add NSLogs, look for delayed searches not getting cancelled when they should.

Comment: how you implement the first option with the NSString? can you write a code example please?

Comment: ok, i'll write something up. Not guaranteed to work error-free though, since I haven't tried this approach in real code.

Comment: whats this line is doing? [self request:searchDelayer.userInfo]; ?

Comment: I have started coding in swift so how can this be done using swift ?

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:
`[self performSelector:@selector(request:) withObject:searchText afterDelay:1.5];`
out of your `textDidChange` method and put it in the text did begin editing method:
`- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`

Comment: but if i add that line in this method: - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar here there isn't the searchText argument, how i can do it...