# Detect Pause when user stop type in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nstimer, uisearchbar

I have the following UISearchbar code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    NSTimer *myTimer;

    NSLog(@"Timer=%@",myTimer);
    if (myTimer)
    {
        if ([myTimer isValid])
        {
            [myTimer invalidate];
        }
        myTimer=nil;
    }
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(OnTextChange) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

after writing above code my log shows `Timer=null`,

`OnTextChange` is method which fetches data from Url.

***Thanks in advance !!***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please write this line in **.h** file

```
NSTimer *myTimer;
```

and then do it in **.m** file

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    NSLog(@"Timer=%@",myTimer);
    if (myTimer)
    {
        if ([myTimer isValid])
        {
            [myTimer invalidate];
        }
        myTimer=nil;
    }
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(OnTextChange) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

every time you are creating new object for NSTimer  that's why it gives null.

declare  `NSTimer *myTimer` globally.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an NSTimer to delay the invocation of your search, and cancel the timer whenever the text changes: Give your object an NSTimer property or field; in searchBar:textDidChange: cancel any existing timer, then create and schedule a new one. The target of the timer should call your search method.

Refer this duplicate question: [UISearchBar detect when user stop type and don't search immediately so detect pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642762/uisearchbar-detect-when-user-stop-type-and-dont-search-immediately-so-detect-pa)