# Swift crashes when canceling a previous task and then creating another one. (NSURLSession)

Tags: ios, swift, request, nsurlsession

im trying to create a simple user search using server requests. Im sending a get request every time the text of the search bar changes. What i want to do is cancel previous tasks/connections when a new one is called. (Every time I press a keyboard key). Im using NSURLSession. The app just crashes when im canceling tasks. Here is my code.

```
var dataTask : NSURLSessionDataTask?
func searchUsers(){

    if (self.dataTask && self.dataTask!.state == NSURLSessionTaskState.Running){
        self.dataTask!.suspend()
        self.dataTask!.cancel()
        self.dataTask = nil
        println("taskRunning")

    }     

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.0.7:3000/users?n=\(searchBox.text.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()))")
    println(searchBox.text)
    self.dataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        userSearch.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        var jsonResult:NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
        println(self.dataTask!.state)
            println(error)
        for index in 0...jsonResult.count-1 {


            var resultDictionary: NSDictionary = jsonResult[index] as NSDictionary
            userSearch.append(User(name: "user" as NSString, id: resultDictionary["_id"] as NSString))

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.resultsTable.reloadData()})


        })

    self.dataTask!.resume()
}
```

Comment: What is the crash message?  Which line?

Comment: i dont really know how to understand error messages of xcode, here is what appears http://s29.postimg.org/bhx4x0ms7/Captura_de_pantalla_2014_08_27_a_la_s_17_43_13.png

Comment: I suspect that what is happening is that you are deallocating the data task in the main thread while the block is still executing in the background thread, so you end up with the block executing in released memory - look at the value of `index` - I doubt you have that many sections - it is random data.  I suspect a better approach may be to start a timer for say 1 or 2 seconds when the search field changes and restart it if they search field changes.  When the timer expires then perform your search against the web service and let it complete even if the search field is changed again

Comment: Ty so much, that alternative worked very well

Comment: Here is the obj c implementation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642762/uisearchbar-detect-when-user-stop-type-and-dont-search-immediately-so-detect-pa