# UISearchBar detect when user stop type in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

Most of the example I found is in `Objective - C` which is very hard for me to understand can someone provide an example regarding this question in `Swift`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642762/uisearchbar-detect-when-user-stop-type-and-dont-search-immediately-so-detect-pa) is one solution but it is in `Objective C`.

Comment: Ask more clearly so that someone can understand!! you can share link link of objective c that you have mentioned!

Comment: Ok i will edit my question.

Comment: Did you try searchBarTextDidEndEditing and searchBarShouldEndEditing ??

Comment: While user typing side by side search proceed, Is it? For this you have to make custom search bar.

Comment: Why u want to do this , it will degrade your application performance

Comment: @SandeepBhandari yes I have already tried using it but can't find solution using those override functions.

Comment: @Amanpreet No I just want to detect the action after when user stops typing .

Answer (score 14):

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print("after every text gets changed")
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.output), userInfo: searchText, repeats: false)
}

func output(){
    print("hello")
    if timer.userInfo != nil {
        print(timer.userInfo)
    }
    timer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: This is how i solved my problem... Thank you everyone for your kind suggestion :)

Comment: Very smart solution. I was looking for async function and how to kill previous async task. This one is much easier and intuitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

## Swift 5

#### Throttled search

Use `NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests` to cancel previous triggers.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.reload), object: nil)
    self.perform(#selector(ViewController.reload), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.5)
}
    
@objc func reload() {
    guard let searchText = searchBar.text else { return }
    search(searchText)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
class WorkItem {

private var pendingRequestWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?

func perform(after: TimeInterval, _ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Cancel the currently pending item
    pendingRequestWorkItem?.cancel()

    // Wrap our request in a work item
    let requestWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem(block: block)

    pendingRequestWorkItem = requestWorkItem

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + after, execute: requestWorkItem)
}
}
```

// to use

```
lazy var workItem = WorkItem()

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange: String) {

    // 0.5 == half second
    workItem.perform(after: 0.5) {

       //Have Stopped, do something.
    }
}
```

References

[Link 1 by swiftbysundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/a-deep-dive-into-grand-central-dispatch-in-swift)

[Link 2 on github](https://github.com/vinhnx/iOS-notes/issues/36)

Comment: Edited, just replace it by `() -> Void`

Answer (score 2):

Swift version of your link:

```
var searchDelayer: Timer!

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchDelayer.invalidate(), searchDelayer = nil
    if true {
        searchDelayer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.doDelayedSearch), userInfo: searchText, repeats: false)
    }
}

func doDelayedSearch(_ t: Timer) {
    assert(t == searchDelayer)
    self.request(searchDelayer.userInfo!)
    searchDelayer = nil
}




var priorSearchText = ""

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(self.request), object: priorSearchText)
        priorSearchText = searchText
    }
    if true {
        self.performSelector(#selector(self.request), withObject: searchText, afterDelay: 1.5)
    }
```

Comment: Am I right that here you showed us two different ways to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check it using UISearchBarDelegate:

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //DO what you want
}
```

Remember to add:

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

And his relative protocol:

```
UISearchBarDelegate
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchbardelegate

That delegate : `searchBarTextDidEndEditing` is called when the keyboard disappears, so add that code to your proj:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("Type End");
    }
Initially I have done the same thing but after when type is end the value is not printed in console so i assume this does not work.

Comment: You have to add: searchBar.delegate = self

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        /* Setup delegates */
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }
Yes i have mention that already.

Comment: check out the new answer

Comment: This is not good answer. He doesn't want to dismiss keyboard, he just wants to inform system that he has stoped typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer: Timer?
            
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    guard let text = searchBar.text else { return }
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.7, repeats: false, block: { _ in
        print(text)
    })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).